# Bootstrap row beneath row gets smaller in width

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't wrap my head around it and it probably is something I am overlooking, but when i want to align my rows in bootstrap, each row I add gets smaller.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your rows are all the same width in my browser. The columns have a default left/right padding of 15px though. Have you tried removing the column paddings? (For example: <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did update it with the solution offered below so It is true the result is the same width. I tend to forget about the default padding after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `width:100%` from your `.action-bar` class, also, put the `row` class on that element instead.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ok you've to change this line

```
<div class="action-bar">
```

into `<div class="row style="  background-color: #555A60;
  margin-top: 50px;"">`
and it will works good